# How to manipulate textview in android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I have this text view in my XML

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

I want to be able to manipulate this from a java method that I'm writing. This is my first android app so I'm not sure. I've read that you can use

```
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01); 
t.setText("new text");
```

however Eclipse is telling me that textview cannot be resolved to be a type. Do I need to import something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

and just import the Textview class do:

```
  if you are using eclipse:  ctrl+shift+O
```

Comment: is there a way to make the new text = a varibale

Comment: what do you mean with "the new text"?

Comment: i meant make the new text the value of a variable. ive worked it out though, just use the varibale name and dont put in the quotes

Answer (score 1):

Your `TextView` ID is `textView1` not `TextView01`. So you should use `R.id.textView1` here:

```
TextView t = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

The ID is defined by `android:id="@+id/textView1"` parameter. Since there is no `TextView` by the ID `TextView01`, you are getting the error.

Comment: t =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Comment: Since it is textView you are defining, it should be as follows: `TextView t = findViewById(R.id.textView1); ` . Using `ctrl+shift+o` to automatically get the relevant import statements. as @Tobel states.

Comment: cannot convert from veiw to textview
edit: never mind i fixed my changing cast

Comment: You need to give more details as to where are you using code to set the text in TextView? Please update the question.

Comment: @HamzahMalik Just a request, you haven't accepted any answers of all the 10 questions that you have asked till now. Please accept the answers that helped you solve your problem. Not accepting answers indicates that the question has not been solved yet. If you are wondering why I am asking please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score -1):

for the error you have specified , you need to import "android.widget.TextView"

Comment: ive just done this but im still getting "t cannot be resolved to be a variable"

Comment: if t can't be resolved then that would mean that "t" is out of scope. for e.g. you have declared t in one method and you are using it in another method. if this is the case then declare your t outside the method as instance variable.

Comment: Could the concerned person please specify why was i downvoted. is it that the answer is not up to the mark or something.I'm bit new to stack overflow